# document.getElementById can't select more than one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on loading. I have div `#loading` which is visible. And more divs `#message` which are hidden. I have js function.

```
function loading() {
     setTimeout(function() {
         document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
         document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
     }, 500, "fadeOut");
 }
```

But that row `document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";` selects only first div `#message`.

```js
function loading() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
  }, 500, "fadeOut");
}
loading();
```

```css
#loading {
  display: block;
}
#message {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="messages" onload="loading();">
  <div id="loading">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="message">
    QWERTY
  </div>
  <div id="message">
    123456
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: An ID has to be unique by definition. You should use the `class` attribute instead.

Comment: use class instead of ID  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: @Saurabh please create answer with code that will agree with my.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others have mentioned `id`s are unique and can only be used once on a page, so use a class instead. Here I've used [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to grab a static list of classes.

The other issue is that you seem to be trying to use jQuery to fade the elements out, but you're not using jQuery for anything else. I'm going to suggest you CSS transitions. They're easy to use, and you don't have the need of loading a huge library. Here I add new classes `fadein` and `fadeout` which (based on your code) increases/reduces the opacity of the specified elements to zero over three seconds.

```js
function loading() {
  setTimeout(function() {

    // use a class for the loader too otherwise the transition
    // won't work properly
    const loader = document.querySelector('.loading');
    loader.classList.add('fadeout');

    // grab the elements with the message class
    const messages = document.querySelectorAll('.message');

    // loop over them and add a fadeout class to each
    [...messages].forEach(message => message.classList.add('fadein'));
  }, 500);
}

loading();
```

```css
.loading {
  opacity: 1;
}

.message {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fadein {
  transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fadeout {
  transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="messages">
  <div class="loading">
    Loading
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    QWERTY
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    123456
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use unique ID's for your DOM elements. Try modify your code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loading() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName('message');
    console.log(el);
    $.each(el, function(i, item){
    item.style.display = 'block';
    });
  }, 500, "fadeOut");
}
loading();
</script>
<style>
#loading {
  display: block;
}
.message{
  display: none;
}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="messages" onload="loading();">
  <div id="loading">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    QWERTY
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    123456
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You haven't tested this code because `document.getElementsByClassName("message").style` definitely won't work.

Comment: @Andy but it's based on php and fetch_object & everywhere there are different count of messages bcs it's chat.

Answer (score 1):

`ID` attribute must be unique. You can't use same ID multiple times on the page. If you like to use same key then use it as a `class` or `data-id` which can be same or differ.

Comment: @WebCoder you're already using class values for some of your elements. The API `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a list of elements that have the requested class. There's also `document.querySelectorAll()`, which is much more powerful.

Comment: Worth pointing out the main difference between the two: QSA returns a static list of nodes rather than a live list of nodes

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have same id twice in a document in order to select multiple elements group them by same Class rather than by id and then use the following to select them all.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".ClassName")
```

Or

```
document.getElementsByClassName(".ClassName");
```

Note that both methods returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name, as a NodeList object.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function loading() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
  }, 500, "fadeOut");
}
loading();
```

```css
#loading {
  display: block;
}
#message {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="messages" onload="loading();">
  <div id="loading">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="message">
    QWERTY
  </div>
  <div id="message">
    123456
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.. its working good and easy to understand this one Excellent

Comment: elements witch has the same id="message"

Comment: Elements witch has the same id="message"