# different answer like document.getElementById(a).style.backgroundColor=red

Tags: javascript, button

I want to make a function that that changes background color of a button but for lots of buttons that only the button pressed changes color
I tried using

```
document.getElementById(a).style.backgroundColor=red
```

but it only changed the first one with the id `a` cant give each one a different id because then I cant have a 1 function but 1 per button

Is there a way to get the id of that button in `getelement…`

I tried `this` but I don't really know how it works.

Comment: I think you forgot quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `id` at all, which is good, because you must not use the same `id` on more than one element in the DOM.

Instead, use a class and `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByClassName` and loop. For instance:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".target").forEach(el => {
    el.style.backgroundColor = "green";
});
```

```html
<div class="target">Target #1</div>
<div class="target">Target #2</div>
<div>Not a target</div>
<div class="target">Target #3</div>
<div>Not a target</div>
<div class="target">Target #4</div>
```

Comment: *There* has *to be a good dupetarget for this... Edit: [Found one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031400/document-getelementbyid-cant-select-more-than-one-element)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll` for selecting more than one element and add events to them to change the color,

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.change-color');

  buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      let current = event.currentTarget
      
      current.style.background = 'red';
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<button class="change-color" data-color="red">Red</button>
<button class="change-color" data-color="blue">Blue</button>
<button class="change-color" data-color="green">Gree</button>
<button class="change-color" data-color="yellow">Yellow</button>
<button class="change-color" data-color="pink">Pink</button>
```